# Elasticsearch get works half of the time

Tags: elasticsearch

I recently ran into a problem with elasticsearch, versions 1.0.1, 1.2.2, 1.2.4, and 1.4.1.

When I try to get a document by ID `GET http://localhost:9200/thing/otherthing/700254a4-4e72-46b9-adeb-d498159652cb` It will return the document half the time, and the other half I will get a `"found" : false` error. (These switch off literally every other time, I do a get and it works, do another get and it doesn't).
These documents have no custom routing.

I have tried completely uninstalling elasticsearch and removing all files related to it, then re installing from the official repo to no avail, and google doesn't give me any similar problems or ideas on how to solve this.

Comment: Do you get a `"found": false` or a 404 (page not found)? Also, do you query the ES server?

Comment: i get a `"found" : false` and yes, that is what happens when i query the server directly.

Comment: Does the mapping for this type specify a parent?

Comment: How do you query it? curl, Marvel sense, something else?

Comment: I have tried with both curl and through a web browser, same result.

Comment: And the mapping does not specify a parent

Comment: How many primary shards do you have defined for this index? How is the cluster configured (how many nodes)?

Comment: What happens if you run this: `GET http://localhost:9200/thing/otherthing/_search?q=_id:700254a4-4e72-46b9-adeb-d498159652cb`

Comment: Search has same result (works every other time), and this is a single node with the default config.

Comment: How many documents do you have in this index?

Comment: Try `GET http://localhost:9200/thing/otherthing/_search?q=_id:700254a4-4e72-46b9-adeb-d49‌​8159652cb&preference=_primary` and `GET http://localhost:9200/thing/otherthing/_search?q=_id:700254a4-4e72-46b9-adeb-d49‌​8159652cb&preference=_local` `

Comment: This index has 268 docs, the `_primary` and `_local` fails

Comment: Hm. Interesting. Any chance you could share the mapping, the entire data and `elasticsearch.yml` file?

Comment: @AndreiStefan I mispoke, `_primary` works but `_local` fails. I must have only typed the "works" bit in my head XD

Comment: Still, I'd like to test this locally. Could you share the details I asked previously?

Comment: Also, if you `GET` other docs, to they fail the same or is this the only doc that fails?

Comment: @AndreiStefan it is all Docs, this only started happening recently and it had been running fine for awhile. The elasticsearch.yml is the defualt one, only thing changed is we set `index.refresh_interval: 1`. the mapping is: http://pastebin.com/DNMmU0G2

Comment: Do you see anything unusual in the logs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only thing I would think of that would cause a repeatable failure like this would be unassigned shards/replica sets which contain this information.

Do you know how many replica sets you have?

I believe the read is round-robin, so if you only have 2 replicas of the data (1 master + a replica set), and 1 has become unassigned (after being written to), then you might see a failure like this.

Comment: that was the problem, multiple nodes were connecting across VMs screwing everything up.